# Display parse notification getting from parse.com as pop up

Tags: android, popup, push-notification, parse-platform

I want to display the message received from **parse push notification** from **parse.com** as a pop up message.

Currently when I select the notification from the tray it only opens the app. I want to be able to display that message in the pop up.

Answer (score 0):

Write one broadcast receiver to handle the push and here is the receiver..

```
public class MyCustomReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    String title, time, msg;

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();

        String message = extras != null ? extras.getString("com.parse.Data")
                : "";

        Log.e("message ", " " + message);

        JSONObject jObject;
        try {
            if (message != null && !message.equals("")) {
                jObject = new JSONObject(message);

            String msg=jObject.getString("msg");

                Intent pupInt = new Intent(context, ShowPopUp.class);
                         Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK );
                                              context.getApplicationContext().startActivity(pupInt);


            }

        }

        catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

}
```

add this to the your manifest

```
<service android:name="com.parse.PushService" />

        <receiver android:name="com.parse.ParseBroadcastReceiver" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.USER_PRESENT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
        <receiver android:name="your package name.MyCustomReceiver" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.USER_PRESENT" />
                <action android:name="your package name.UPDATE_STATUS" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
```

your popup message class...

```
public class ShowPopUp extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

    Button ok;
    Button cancel;

    boolean click = true;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setTitle("Message");
        setContentView(R.layout.popupdialog);
        ok = (Button)findViewById(R.id.popOkB);
        ok.setOnClickListener(this);
        cancel = (Button)findViewById(R.id.popCancelB);
        cancel.setOnClickListener(this);

    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        finish();
    }
}
```

use this code to send push notification

```
push.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                JSONObject obj;
                try {

                    obj = new JSONObject();
                    obj.put("alert", "tiltle of your push");
                    obj.put("action", "your package name.UPDATE_STATUS");


                    obj.put("msg", "push test");


                    ParsePush push = new ParsePush();
                    ParseQuery query = ParseInstallation.getQuery();

                    query.whereEqualTo("deviceType", "android");

                    push.setQuery(query);
                    push.setData(obj);
                    push.sendInBackground();


                } catch (JSONException e) {

                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Message Sent", 10000).show();
            }
        });
```

hope your problem will be solved....

Comment: :-Its not working.no any error but the notification not received.

Comment: I dont want to send the notification.I just want to receive the notification directly on pop-up coming from my parse dashboard.

Comment: { "action": "your package name.UPDATE_STATUS",  "msg": "push test","alert": "text" } send push from your parse dashboard like this format..

Comment: How can i send this from my parse dashboard.???.this will only include an alert not an action or msg something like that.